# Switched fuse always on

Tags: ignition, wiring, gps

Wondering if someone can help. I am putting in a GPS unit in my friends truck. Not the first time I've done this in his truck. Last time we ran the red ignition wire to his fuse box using the supplied red ignition wire that came with his aftermarket harness that has the female end to it. We plugged that into the fuse panel and all worked well.

His old unit was stolen so now we are putting in a new one. All wired the same way, except this time the unit is getting power all the time instead of switched. If I unplugged the red wire I get nothing. So it does see like for some reason his switched ignition port is getting a constant feed now.

Any ideas of how this is happening or if there is something else I am missing?

Sorry for the lack of technical terms as I am no expert. TIA

Comment: I would suggest that you have plugged it into the wrong slot on the fuse box... Get a multimeter and check...

Comment: That's what I'm going to do later today but wanted to see if someone had an answer. I thought all of the single slot connections in fuse boxes were all switched. That was their purpose and why in wiring kits you are given that long red wire with the female connection.

Comment: The fuse boxes have permanent supplies, ignition switched supplies and supplies depending on the position of the light switch just to pick some obvious ones... Just get the multimeter and check - you should be able to see from the fuse number and the legend the purpose of each fuse and work out when it would be live....

Comment: " I thought all of the single slot connections in fuse boxes were all switched" Not true. Some are Hot at all times.